# Error When trying to use an Expression Tree in a Where() clause when using EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I'm getting an error while tring to compose an `Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>>` by combining other expressions. The intent is to use it in the where() clause of an EFCore query. Example:

```
// Only get users that have been forwarded the request...
var request = GetSomeRequestToFilterOn();
var filter = HasRequestBeenForwaredToUserExpression().ReplaceParameter(request);
var results = _context.ApplicationUsers.Where(filter).ToList();
```

In the example above I am converting an `Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, TransferRequest, bool>>` into and `Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>>` by replacing the TransferRequest parameter in the expression with the one provided. This works great in my unit tests, but EFCore doesn't seem to like it, and I get this error when running against the actual database:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Rewriting child expression from type `System.Nullable<System.DateTime>` to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Nullable<System.DateTime>>`
>   is not allowed, because it would change the meaning of the operation.
>   If this is intentional, override 'VisitUnary' and change it to allow
>   this rewrite. at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.ValidateChildType(Type
>   before, Type after, String methodName) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.ValidateUnary(UnaryExpression
>   before, UnaryExpression after) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression
>   node) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   node) at...

Basically, a person is considered to have been 'forwarded' the transfer request if there are any 'forwarded' events after the last 'awaiting approval' event, i.e. when there is a new 'awaiting approval' event the previous 'forwarded' events don't count anymore (but still exist).

Here is my Filter.

```
internal static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, TransferRequest, bool>> HasRequestBeenForwaredToUserExpression()
{
    //only "Forwarded" events after the last "Awaiting Approval" event count.
    //so we need to get the last "Awaiting Approval" event from the request.
    var projection = LastAwaitingApprovalEvent();

    var userParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ApplicationUser));
    var requestParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TransferRequest));
    var requestToEvent = projection.Body.ReplaceParameter(projection.Parameters[0], requestParam);

    Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, TransferRequest, TransferRequestEvent, bool>> condition =
       (user, rqst, evt) => evt != null && rqst.TransferRequestEvents
            .Any(e2 =>
                Equals(e2.EventType, EventType.Forwarded) &&
                Equals(e2.User, user) &&
                e2.EventDateTime > evt.EventDateTime);

    var body = condition.Body
            .ReplaceParameter(condition.Parameters[0], userParam)
            .ReplaceParameter(condition.Parameters[1], requestParam)
            .ReplaceParameter(condition.Parameters[2], requestToEvent);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<ApplicationUser, TransferRequest, bool>>(body, userParam, requestParam);
}
```

This method gets the last "Awaiting Approval" event

```
internal static Expression<Func<TransferRequest, TransferRequestEvent>> LastAwaitingApprovalEvent()
{
    return t => t.TransferRequestEvents
        .OrderBy(e => e.EventDateTime).ThenBy(e => e.Id)
        .LastOrDefault(e => Equals(e.EventType, EventType.AwaitingReview));
}
```

I have an ExpressionUtility class that does the work of replacing parameters:

```
public class ExpressionUtility
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression,
        ParameterExpression toReplace,
        Expression newExpression)
    {
        return new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression)
            .Visit(expression);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TArg2, TReturn>> ReplaceParameter<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> source, TArg1 arg1)
    {
        var t1Param = Expression.Constant(arg1);
        var t2Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg2));
        var body = source.Body
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], t1Param)
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[1], t2Param);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg2, TReturn>>(body, t2Param);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TArg1, TReturn>> ReplaceParameter<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> source, TArg2 arg2)
    {
        var t1Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg1));
        var t2Param = Expression.Constant(arg2);
        var body = source.Body
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], t1Param)
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[1], t2Param);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TReturn>>(body, t1Param);
    }
}

public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression from;
    private Expression to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

### ***edit***

When I print the final Expression's ToString to the Console. I get

> {Param_0 =>
>   ((value(Debugging.Models.TransferRequest).TransferRequestEvents.OrderBy(e
>   => e.EventDateTime).ThenBy(e => e.Id).LastOrDefault(e => Equals(e.EventType, EventType.AwaitingReview)) != null) AndAlso
>   value(Debugging.Models.TransferRequest).TransferRequestEvents.Any(e2
>   => ((Equals(e2.EventType, EventType.Forwarded) AndAlso Equals(e2.User, Param_0)) AndAlso (e2.EventDateTime >
>   value(Debugging.Models.TransferRequest).TransferRequestEvents.OrderBy(e
>   => e.EventDateTime).ThenBy(e => e.Id).LastOrDefault(e => Equals(e.EventType, EventType.AwaitingReview)).EventDateTime))))}

Also, the following code works just fine

```
Expression<Func<string, ApplicationUser, bool>> filter = (s, u) => u.FirstName.Contains(s);
var whereClause= filter.ReplaceParameter("mark");
_context.AppicationUsers.Where(whereClause).ToList();
```